# React Material UI – using UI Grid to split screen in half with one half scrollable and other half fixed

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have two Grid components one of which is setup like this

```
<Grid container alignItems="stretch" spacing={3}>
  <Grid className="left-pane" item md={4} xs={12}>
    <Navigation />
  </Grid>
  <Grid className="right-pane" item md={8} xs={12}>
    <img src={Background} />
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1>
    <h1>Test</h1>
  </Grid>
</Grid>;
```

I want to make it such that the left-pane is fixed and the right-pane is scrollable. When making left-pane fixed – shifts to the left overlapping the left pane. How do I do this within Material UI React so where it allows the left to stay fixed and the right to stay scrollable. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Try using `grid-template-areas` and assigned `grid-area` grid CSS. [CSS Complete Guide Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas)

Answer (score 0):

You should use react material drawer https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/. Here grid is monkey patch solution.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Hidden from '@material-ui/core/Hidden';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
  },
  drawer: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: drawerWidth,
      flexShrink: 0,
    },
  },
  appBar: {
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
      marginLeft: drawerWidth,
    },
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginRight: theme.spacing(2),
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      display: 'none',
    },
  },
  // necessary for content to be below app bar
  toolbar: theme.mixins.toolbar,
  drawerPaper: {
    width: drawerWidth,
  },
  content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
  },
}));

function ResponsiveDrawer(props) {
  const { container } = props;
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();
  const [mobileOpen, setMobileOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleDrawerToggle = () => {
    setMobileOpen(!mobileOpen);
  };

  const drawer = (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.toolbar} />
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
      <Divider />
      <List>
        {['All mail', 'Trash', 'Spam'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem button key={text}>
            <ListItemIcon>{index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}</ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={text} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <AppBar position="fixed" className={classes.appBar}>
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton
            color="inherit"
            aria-label="open drawer"
            edge="start"
            onClick={handleDrawerToggle}
            className={classes.menuButton}
          >
            <MenuIcon />
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
            Responsive drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
      <nav className={classes.drawer} aria-label="mailbox folders">
        {/* The implementation can be swapped with js to avoid SEO duplication of links. */}
        <Hidden smUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            container={container}
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={theme.direction === 'rtl' ? 'right' : 'left'}
            open={mobileOpen}
            onClose={handleDrawerToggle}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            ModalProps={{
              keepMounted: true, // Better open performance on mobile.
            }}
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
        <Hidden xsDown implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper,
            }}
            variant="permanent"
            open
          >
            {drawer}
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </nav>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.toolbar} />
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
          ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum
          facilisis leo vel. Risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Semper risus in hendrerit
          gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id
          donec ultrices. Odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing. Amet nisl suscipit
          adipiscing bibendum est ultricies integer quis. Cursus euismod quis viverra nibh cras.
          Metus vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo. Mauris commodo quis
          imperdiet massa tincidunt. Cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. At augue eget
          arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem. Velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Lorem
          donec massa sapien faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla
          facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac
          tincidunt. Ornare suspendisse sed nisi lacus sed viverra tellus. Purus sit amet volutpat
          consequat mauris. Elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi. Euismod lacinia at quis risus sed
          vulputate odio. Morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget egestas purus viverra accumsan in. In
          hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci ac. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et
          tortor. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin
          nibh sit. Ornare aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend. Commodo viverra maecenas
          accumsan lacus vel facilisis. Nulla posuere sollicitudin aliquam ultrices sagittis orci a.
        </Typography>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

ResponsiveDrawer.propTypes = {
  /**
   * Injected by the documentation to work in an iframe.
   * You won't need it on your project.
   */
  container: PropTypes.any,
};

export default ResponsiveDrawer;
```